# ¿Se puede limitar el consumo de recursos para que no se quede inutilizado el equipo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

En ocasiones mis scripts requieren muchos recursos y se me queda inutilizado el equipo. 
Me gustaría saber cómo limitar el acceso de mis scripts a los recursos del equipo. Por ejemplo, no dejarle usar más de un 50%.

Uso el interprete Spyder. Pero no he encontrado ninguna opción en la configuración.

El SO es Windows 7

Comment: Desde python no lo sé, pero en linux tienes comandos para hacerlo. Mira este enlace http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups Podrías hacer que tu proceso se autogestionara la cpu

Comment: Se me ocurre ejecutar comandos del sistema para sacar el PID del proceso de tu programa y luego utilizar otro comando desde tu programa para auto-limitarse los recursos. Si dices en qué sistema operativo lo quieres hacer, podría darte los comandos.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un mini ejemplo de la idea que te comenté le otro día. El comando de **renice** en **linux** te permite asignar la prioridad de un proceso.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import time

def main():
    process_pid = os.getpid()

    return_code = subprocess.call("renice -n -19 " + str(process_pid), shell=True)

    if return_code != 0:
        print("Error no pude cambiar la prioridad de " + str(process_pid))

    print("Proceso " + str(process_pid))

    start_time = time.time()
    stop_time = start_time  + 30 # 30 segundos

    while True:
        if (time.time()) >= stop_time:
            print("Paramos")
            break

    print("FIN")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Mi SO es W7. En cualquier caso, no entiendo bien cómo funciona el código que muestras ni cómo/cuándo usarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Sin conocer el código de los scripts que ejecutas es difícil poder ayudar. Sin embargo, podrías incorporar generadores de python (en el caso de que no lo hayas hecho) porque mejoran sustancialmente el rendimiento. En este enlace hay una explicación y ejemplo de generador: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLVnoqXGWpY

Dejo un código de ejemplo por si pudiera servir:

```
def generador():
    for i in range(10):
        yield int(i)


def principal():
    for num in generador():
        number=num+10
        print (number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    principal()
```

Comment: Me pasa con varios scripts, por lo que busco una forma general de hacerlo. Gracias por el enlace, le voy a echar un vistazo.

Comment: Usar generadores no resuelve mi problema, pero gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes reducir la prioridad del proceso en el administrador de tareas:

Ctrl + Shift + Esc > Pestaña procesos > Click derecho > Establecer prioridad.

Puedes probar con "Baja" o "Por debajo de lo normal" y ver si mejora la respuesta del sistema.

Comment: En ocasiones ni tan siquiera puedo acceder al administrador de tareas, pero lo tendré en cuenta.